# Why is rsync modifying unchanged files and directories?

Tags: rsync

If I create two directories with the same name but different modification times:

```
$ mkdir -p dir1/dir ; sleep 2 ; mkdir -p dir2/dir

$ stat -c %y dir*/dir
2021-09-15 10:54:55.000819360 +0100
2021-09-15 10:54:57.007490593 +0100
```

And then use `rsync` with the `--size-only` option:

```
$ rsync -rtvh --size-only dir1/ dir2/
sending incremental file list
./
dir/

sent 72 bytes  received 23 bytes  190.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

I expect nothing to change, because the sizes are the same. However, the modification time of `dir2/dir` does get changed:

```
$ stat -c %y dir*/dir
2021-09-15 10:54:55.000819360 +0100
2021-09-15 10:54:55.000819360 +0100
```

This also happens to files when the sizes are identical.

Why is it doing this?

This also happens if a directory contains lots of data (other nested directories and files). Is the directory actually being overwritten, or is rsync merely updating the timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rsync is simply updating the metadata (only) to match as you asked it to with the `-t` flag.

If you look at the manual (type `man rsync`) read read the description:

> Rsync finds files that need to be transferred using a "quick check" algorithm (by default) that looks for files that have changed in size or in last-modified time.  Any changes in  the  other  pre‐
> served attributes (as requested by options) are made on the destination file directly when the quick check indicates that the file's data does not need to be updated.

The `--size-only` flag only changes this "quick check" algorithm, it doesn't completely skip the files:

> --size-only
>
> This  modifies rsync's "quick check" algorithm for finding files that need to be transferred, changing it from the default of transferring files with either a changed size or a changed last-modified time to just looking for files that have changed in size.  This is useful when starting to use rsync after using another mirroring system which may not preserve timestamps exactly.